# How to run React JS app on phone on local server

Tags: reactjs

I have just started learning react JS

I have created my first app using create-react-app when I run it using

`npm start`

then I am able to see the my react app on my pc on local host server but on putting the address provided in terminal(Check Photo) to my phone I am not able to visit the site

[image]

When i run the

`http://192.168.150.1:3000`

on my pc I am able to see my react app but on putting the same address in my phone I am not able to see my react app

Both my pc and phone are on the same private network

I have also tried with the all the IPv4 which were there in cmd

`ipconfig`

Comment: Maybe your firewall is blocking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run your react js website on your phone then you need to follow the below

1.Connect both the device to same network you can also use your phone hotspot

2.run `ipconfig` command in cmd

3.Under the **Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi** section there will be **IPv4 Address** copy that

4.Then paste the IPv4 Address on your phone and after the IP address type the port address, in the above case it is 3000

5.It will run the website on your phone

you can use the above to run your basic static website also that you have coded using basic HTML for that you have to the same first type the IPv4 Address and then the port number (ex.5500)

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of 3 possibles reasons as to why this happens

1. Firewall restrictions for incoming connections
2. You might need port forwarding
3. Some kind of mobile restriction?

Have you tried with devices other than your phone?

Comment: I am only having 1 device so it is not possible for me to check on other devices. How I can resolve this issue